# Bioinformatics tool for "pairwise alignment" of complementary sequences?

Tags: bioinformatics, rna, blast

I'm currently working on some ribozyme binding, and I'm looking for a tool that will essentially analyze the regions of the degree of complementarity in two sequences in order to extrapolate efficiency of binding. After thinking about it, I'm essentially looking for "the opposite" of BLAST, in that BLAST looks for regions of *similarity* in sequences in the *same* orientation, while I'm looking for  regions of *complementarity* in sequence in the *opposite* orientation.

**Does such a tool exist?**

**EDIT 1**

To clarify, I'm looking for a tool that can detect the most optimal regions of complementarity in two sequences when both are aligned as such:

> 5' TCGAAUAACTCGTCUGAUGAGUCGCUGAAAUGCGACGAAACCGTTAACGGA 3'
>
> 3'   GTTTTACGCAAAGCAGCGTAAAGTCGCTGAGTAGTCACTTTAATGAC   5'

Comment: The opposite? You mean regions of low similarity or actually complementary? If the latter, just use translated blast flavors. If you post an example sequence to clarify, I should be able to give you a precise answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: looking for regions of high complementarity. Will edit question in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you need since the sequences you posted are not actually complementary as far as I can tell. However, [`exonerate`](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/~guy/exonerate/) is one of the most powerful tools out there and can do this as well. Using these sequences as examples:

> >query
>   TAGCTTATTGATGGGAGGAGAGTCCGTGCACATGACAGACCTTGGCTGTCCCAGACTGCAGGAAGCCCAGG
>   >target
>   CCTGGGCTTCCTGCAGTCTGGGACAGCCAAGTCTGTTATGTGCACGTACTCTCCTCCCCTCAATAAGCTA

And this command (should be run on a *nix system):

```
exonerate -m coding2coding -q qq.fa -t test.fa -s 0
```

I get this output:

```
C4 Alignment:
------------
         Query: query [revcomp]
        Target: target
         Model: genome2genome
     Raw score: 312
   Query range: 71 -> 0
  Target range: 0 -> 70

 71 :                                                          CCA       :  6
      CCTGGGCTTCCTGCAGTCTGGGACAGCCAAGGTCTGTCATGTGCACGGACTCTCCTCProTCAATA
      |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||| ||||||||| |||||||||||+||||||
      CCTGGGCTTCCTGCAGTCTGGGACAGCCAA-GTCTGTTATGTGCACGTACTCTCCTCProTCAATA
  1 :                                                          CCC       : 65

  5 : AGCTA :  1
      |||||
 66 : AGCTA : 70

vulgar: query 71 0 - target 0 70 + 312 M 30 30 G 1 0 M 26 26 C 3 3 M 11 11

C4 Alignment:
------------
         Query: query
        Target: target [revcomp]
         Model: genome2genome
     Raw score: 309
   Query range: 0 -> 71
  Target range: 70 -> 0

  1 :                      GTC                                           : 66
      TAGCTTATTGATGGGAGGAGAValCGTGCACATGACAGACCTTGGCTGTCCCAGACTGCAGGAAGC
      ||||||||||| |||||||||||+||||||||| ||||| ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
      TAGCTTATTGAGGGGAGGAGAValCGTGCACATAACAGA-CTTGGCTGTCCCAGACTGCAGGAAGC
 70 :                      GTA                                           :  6

 67 : CCAGG : 71
      |||||
  5 : CCAGG :  1

vulgar: query 0 71 + target 70 0 - 309 M 21 21 C 3 3 M 15 15 G 1 0 M 31 31
```

Basically it gives you two alignments, one reading the target 3->5 and the query 5->3 and one the other way around.

Alternatively, you could do a translated blast search, tBLASTx which will translate both target and query sequence and so, should find complementary regions.

Comment: Is that where you grabbed yours?  I just installed it and got different results.  Some of it is visual (AA names, 1 versus 0-based indexing) but the scores are pretty different.

Comment: @Amory I'm using the one from the Debian repos, v. 2.2.0. Yes, the page you linked to is the homepage, so I'm guessing you just got a newer version and they've changed the algorithm a bit. Perhaps a different scoring matrix. In any case, the score here is irrelevant since it will depend directly on the length of the sequence.

Comment: @terdon On second thought, would doing a regular pairwise alignment with the reverse-complement of only of the sequences yield the same result?

Comment: @LanceLafontaine probably but it will be slower and perhaps less accurate. If you are looking for possibly complementary sequences that can bind to each other I would use something like exonerate or blast rather than a sequence aligner.

Comment: @terdon: I dont understand why you suggested tblast. Translation has got no relation to complementarity.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I recommended tBLASTx. tBLASTx will translate input sequences in all 6 frames which includes the - strand which is the reverse complement of the + strand. Therefore, it can be used to find complementary sequences since the 5'->3' translation of the plus strand will be the 3'->5' translation of the - strand.

Comment: yes but same translational product can arise with different codons and therefore you wont be able to assess complementarity..

Comment: @WYSIWYG indeed, I am just very used to translated blast searches and it was the first thing I thought of because they will also show weaker complimentarity. Since most homonymous codons change only in the wobble position, you might be able to spot complimentarity more easily precisely because of the code's redundancy. In any case, `exonerate` was my first suggestion, and I agree that your simple nucleotide blast is probably better than translations.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a tool to estimate the binding affinities of the two sequences, i.e. OligoCalc

http://www.basic.northwestern.edu/biotools/OligoCalc.html

Answer (score 2):

Just run blast with only the `Plus-Minus` alignments. See [this](http://www.biostars.org/p/51697/) post in biostar; it is similar to what you are interested in. This is for the standalone version. I am not sure about how to do it in the online blast. 
If you have just two sequences then you can use UNAfold for checking complementarity.